# Consumir webservice JAVA - Problema

Tags: java, web-service, netbeans

Estou tentando consumir o webservice porem está dando um erro que não entendo. O webservice é [este](http://webservicescolhomologacao.correios.com.br/ScolWeb/WebServiceScol?wsdl).

Estou tentando utilizar o `solicitarRange`, e normalmente eu faço assim:

```
new WebServiceScol_Service().getWebServiceScolPort().solicitarRange(
                                                                    "60618043",
                                                                    "8o8otn",
                                                                    8082650,
                                                                    new Long("9912208555"),
                                                                    "LE",
                                                                    "",
                                                                    1);
```

Só que ele está dando o seguinte erro:

> error: package br.com.correios.scol.webservice does not exist
>
> import br.com.correios.scol.webservice.RetornoFaixaNumericaTO;

Ele nem chega a entrar na ação, ele dá erro nos `import`, eu estou usando o netbeans e não está acusando erro, até porque as classes existem, alguem tem alguma ideia?

Link do manual [aqui](http://www.corporativo.correios.com.br/encomendas/sigepweb/doc/Manual_de_Implementacao_do_Web_Service_SIGEPWEB_Logistica_Reversa.pdf), pagina 31.

Comment: Tá meio bagunçado sua pergunta, você quis dizer que a linha do código do `import` do pacote está dando erro?

Comment: Tenta fazer a requisição com o [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/). Vai ver o erro está ocorrendo do lado de lá.

Comment: no Soap está funcionando corretamente, até agora não entendi o porque do erro. Ele ta falando que os import que eu preciso fazer não existe... alguem tem alguma idéia??

Comment: Esse erro é durante a execução ou compilação?

Comment: Acabei de mandar compilar e deu certo, pelo visto era esse o problema, vou mexer aqui qualquer coisa volto a questionar